# vim set number not working on InsertEnter

Tags: vim

As you will see from my vimrc file below I am trying to 'set number' on InsertEnter. In normal mode I use 'set relativenumber' to make it easier to more around with j,k. The config below work on my macbook but not on a RHEL box i'm running. Instead of doing 'set number' for the whole file when I enter Insert mode it sets number only for the line I am on. The rest of the file lines continue to display as relativenumbers.

How do I fix this? Any idea what is going on here?

```
execute pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()
syntax on
syntax enable
filetype plugin indent on
colorscheme molokai
set rnu
autocmd FocusLost * :set number
autocmd FocusGained * :set rnu
autocmd InsertEnter * :set number
autocmd InsertLeave * :set rnu
set rtp +=/home/evolution/.vim/bundle/powerline/powerline/bindings/vim
set splitright
set ttymouse=xterm2
set backspace=2
set laststatus=2
set t_Co=256
set laststatus=2
set showtabline=2
set noshowmode
set nocompatible
set background=dark
set shiftwidth=4  " operation >> indents 4 columns; << unindents 4 columns
set tabstop=4     " a hard TAB displays as 4 columns
set expandtab     " insert spaces when hitting TABs
set softtabstop=4 " insert/delete 4 spaces when hitting a TAB/BACKSPACE
set shiftround    " round indent to multiple of 'shiftwidth'
set autoindent    " align the new line indent with the previous line
set cursorline
hi CursorLine   cterm=NONE ctermbg=52

let g:CommandTAcceptSelectionMap = '<C-t>'
let g:CommandTAcceptSelectionTabMap = '<CR>'
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1

noremap <Up> <NOP>
noremap <Down> <NOP>
noremap <Left> <NOP>
noremap <Right> <NOP>

map  <C-l> :tabn<CR>
map  <C-h> :tabp<CR>
```

Comment: Most likely a terminal display refresh issue.  Try doing a CTRL+L or a :redraw.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thing is that in order to do either of those things I need to exit insert mode in which case I want to see relative numbers. One other thing I did try was writing a function that to set number and redraw. That didn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

I found that this works:

```
set rnu
function ToggleNumbersOn()
    set rnu!
    set nu
endfunction
function ToggleRelativeOn()
    set nu!
    set rnu
endfunction
autocmd FocusLost * call ToggleNumbersOn()
autocmd FocusGained * call ToggleRelativeOn()
autocmd InsertEnter * call ToggleNumbersOn()
autocmd InsertLeave * call ToggleRelativeOn()
```

Comment: What worked for me was to react to FocusGained and FocusLost events. It apparently works only on GUI and some terminals - thankfully it worked on urxvt on Linux :D

Answer (score 0):

Replace the autocommand with `set number` by set `nornu`

```
set nu
autocmd InsertEnter * :set nornu
autocmd InsertLeave * :set rnu
```

Mark as fixed when fixed

Answer (score -1):

You may be interested in Vim 7.4 hybrid relative-absolute number mode.

```
set relativenumber 
set number
```

This will show relative numbers but what would be zero will be the current line number.

However if that won't work for you then there are a few plugins that do what you ask: [numbers.vim](https://github.com/myusuf3/numbers.vim/) and [numbertoggle](https://github.com/jeffkreeftmeijer/vim-numbertoggle)